# ARDUINO analog input & LED

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I take analog input from force sensor and can see them real time on serial monitor. The simple code I wrote for this is

```
int SensorIn1 = 1;

void setup() {

Serial.begin (9600);

}

void loop() {

Serial.println(analogRead(SensorIn1));
delay (100);
}
```

Now I need to lit a LED when the input values remain > 1000 for more than 5 sec until it goes below 1000 again. can anyone help me with sample code to perform this??  # I am Using ARDUINO UNO.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to answer this question yourself?  It would help if you suggested what you already attempted, it will make it easier to help you out :)

Completely untested suggestion below, should give you something to go on..

```
int SensorIn1 = 1;
int led_pin = 13;
long gone_high_time = 0; // set to zero if input is not high
                         // set to time input went high if input is high

void setup() {
    Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
    int val;
    val = analogRead(SensorIn1);
    Serial.println(val);
    if (val > 1000) {
        if (gone_high_time == 0) {
            gone_high_time = millis();
        } else if (millis() - gone_high_time > 5000) {
            digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
        }   
    } else {
        gone_high_time = 0;
        digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
    }
    delay (100);
}
```